# Google cloud Speech to Text API - Email address transcript

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

Is there any way to get email address transcribed properly?

What it does at the moment is if you say 'habjan@domain.com' it gets transcribed to something like 'habjan at domain dot com.

I'm wondering is there some hint that you can say to switch engine to different context?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend enabling [punctuation](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/speech/gapic/v1p1beta1/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1.types.RecognitionConfig.enable_automatic_punctuation), then you can try to enhance the request with adding [speech context](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/speech/gapic/v1p1beta1/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1.types.RecognitionConfig.speech_contexts)
and potential expected [phrases](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/speech/gapic/v1p1beta1/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1.types.SpeechContext.phrases).

Comment: Averi, could you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117877/specify-region-for-google-speech-api