# Specify Region for Google Speech API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

We are using Google Speech API as part of our service. Due to new GDPR rules we have to make sure none of our data leaves the EU. All other services seems to be able to specify a region including Google Cloud Storage. However, I haven't been able to find any documentation related to Google Speech API.

Anybody know if it is possible to specify a region for Google Speech API to avoid sending our data outside the EU?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this question.

Google now supports regional endpoints for Speech-to-Text: 
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/endpoints

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer: https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/?region=europe#region

Short answer, NO! Google Speech is not available within Europe.