# Google Text-to-speech - How to specify region EU?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-text-to-speech

I'm using Google Cloud Text-to-speech to synthesize speech from text. How can I specify the region for the API calls? This is similar to this question [Specify Region for Google Speech API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117877/specify-region-for-google-speech-api) but my question is for text-to-speech, not speech-to-text.

For speech-to-text there wasn't an available endpoint in Europe but there is one now: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/endpoints

I can't find the same type of endpoint documentation for text-to-speech, the closest I find is this page: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest that specifies a single endpoint: https://texttospeech.googleapis.com

Does this mean that I cannot keep the text-to-speech requests within Europe? It could also be that the region is fetched from the Google Cloud project region or something like that but I cannot find such an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specifying of region for text-to-speech API that you are asking for is currently a requested feature in GCP public issue tracker. You can track the progress with [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140834676) link.